# problem to use selector after document ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using `.load()` in get data as php file
do when get value by selector get `null`

load code

```js
    $("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");
```

in to php file

```html
    <button  class="btn btn-success  ml-1 mr-1 btnentergame" name="btn_enter" value="154">enter the game</button>
```

and selector code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnentergame").click(function () {
         var valuu = $(this).val();
         alert(valuu);       
    });
});
```

I am test `.on()` and `.bind` but not work

Comment: I'm afraid it's not too clear what your problem actually is. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I can not select element that in loaded

Comment: event click not work

Comment: Where are you calling `$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");`? And what do you mean by, *in to php file*? Do you mean the PHP script generates the `button` element you're showing?

Comment: `$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");` this returns the button you're trying to add the click listener to?

Comment: yes my button in the php file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(document).ready()` doesn't wait for

```
$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1");
```

to be completed. So you're adding a click listener to an element which doesn't exist yet at this point in time.

Instead you need to add a callback function to the load method and add the click listener there.

```
$("#tr1").load("include/test.php?page=1", function() {
  $(".btnentergame").click(function() {
    var valuu = $(this).val();
    alert(valuu);

  });
});
```